# Hard drive constraints and operating system for 2009 13" macbook

Tags: macos, mac

I was given a 2009 13" macbook, but it needs a new hard drive and operating system.

What is the most current OS it can handle and how much space does that OS take when freshly installed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Hardware shopping is off topic so I edited that part out. There should be lots of questions already on upgrade technical details for the MacBook that takes a hard drive next to the removable battery. Ramjet.com and owc.com such can get you options quickly

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBook can support anything up to and including High Sierra (the next OS release), but will not have Handoff due to the computer not supporting Bluetooth 4.0.
[source](https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility)

As for the install space, [lifewire’s article](https://www.lifewire.com/minimum-requirements-for-running-macos-sierra-4055648) says that you should have 16GB of space *minimum* for the install, though 32GB is recommended.

Comment: Hardware shopping is off topic, but stating a model is compatible is just fine in answers. Can you add the size of Sierra install? That would fit the edited post quite well and likely get back accepted check.

Comment: @bmike gotcha. morning brain wasn’t thinking about SE rules :). I’ll research and edit.